# Why align="right" works but not text-align:right for a td?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align some content in a td to the right. align="right" works but text-align:right does not. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9VBu) example that shows the two cases. The two cases are the same except for right aligning the right column. As you can see, in the second case, 'button 1" is aligned to the left when I was expecting it to be aligned to the right.

**Addition:**

I am using third party controls which add the tables. So no "You should use css and not tables discussions please".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`text-align` aligns text. It does not affect block-level elements like nested tables. `align="right"`, on the other hand, aligns everything in a brute-force manner (akin to `<center>`).

Nested tables are generally a horrible idea anyway, so should be avoided. If you must use a nested table, apply `margin-left: auto;` to the nested table to have it aligned to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice in your fiddle the **TEXT IS aligned right**.

You are trying to align a table  which is why `align="right"` works.

**Note:**
You should also not that using table's for formatting anything other than tabular data is an out of date practice.  You should use `<div>` and CSS to layout your page in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="border: 1px solid red;" align="right">
    <table style="width: 60px;background-color: #ffccff">
```

It's aligning the table to the right within the TD entity.

```
<td style="border: 1px solid red;text-align:right">
```

It's keeping the table aligned to the left, but right aligning the text within that table.